# How to have one component method call another component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular6

`signin.component.ts` (child component)

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Data, AppService } from '../../app.service';
import { emailValidator, matchingPasswords } from '../../theme/utils/app-validators';
import { TopMenuComponent } from '../../theme/components/top-menu/top-menu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild(TopMenuComponent) top !: TopMenuComponent;
  @Input() hero: TopMenuComponent;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public router:Router, public snackBar: MatSnackBar,private appservie:AppService)
   {
     localStorage.clear()
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])] 
    });

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirmPassword': ['', Validators.required]
    },{validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')});

  }

  public onLoginFormSubmit(values:Object):void {
    console.log(values)
    this.appservie.loginuser(JSON.stringify(values)).subscribe(response =>{
      var data = response
      console.log(data)
      console.log(data['user']['username'])
      localStorage.setItem('username',data['user']['username'])
      console.log(this.hero.Message)
    })
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);

    }
  }

  public onRegisterFormSubmit(values:Object):void {
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
      this.snackBar.open('You registered successfully!', '×', { panelClass: 'success', verticalPosition: 'top', duration: 3000 });
    }
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() 
  {

  }

}
```

`topmenucomponet.ts` (parent component)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Data, AppService } from '../../../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-menu',
  templateUrl: './top-menu.component.html'
})
export class TopMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public currencies = ['USD', 'EUR'];
  public currency:any;
  public flags = [
    { name:'English', image: 'assets/images/flags/gb.svg' },
    { name:'German', image: 'assets/images/flags/de.svg' },
    { name:'French', image: 'assets/images/flags/fr.svg' },
    { name:'Russian', image: 'assets/images/flags/ru.svg' },
    { name:'Turkish', image: 'assets/images/flags/tr.svg' }
  ]
  public flag:any;

  data:any;
  public Message="hai"
  constructor(public appService:AppService) 
  {
   this.data = localStorage.getItem('username')

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currency = this.currencies[0];
    this.flag = this.flags[0];    
  }

  public changeCurrency(currency){
    this.currency = currency;
  }

  public changeLang(flag){
    this.flag = flag;
  }

   value()
  {
    return 'hai'
  }
}
```

I tried but it's not working. I want to access in (topmenu.component.ts) message in (sigin.component.ts). Can you provide any suggestions how to access one component and another component value or method? I am using various concept viewchild and input but its not working is showing error for cannot read property message value.

Comment: use behaviour subject or output property binding

Comment: can give any example code.

Comment: please provide a template where you use these components

Comment: why don't you just use Output?

Comment: one component pages folder and another component theme folder

Comment: I tried all functionalities viewchild, input, outpu,t but showing cannot read property message.

Answer (score 0):

Inside appservie service file import behavioursubject from rxjs

```
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

Then define BehaviorSubject

```
formValue= new BehaviorSubject({'username':''});
```

use next method to share data across component

**Parent Component**

```
 public onLoginFormSubmit(values:Object):void {
    console.log(values)
    this.appservie.loginuser(JSON.stringify(values)).subscribe(response =>{
      var data = response
      console.log(data)
      console.log(data['user']['username'])
  if(data['user']['username']){
   this.formValue.next({'username':data['user']['username']});
  }
    })
```

Subscribe the data in child component

**Child Component**

```
constructor(private appService:AppService) 
  {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.formValue.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
  })
    this.currency = this.currencies[0];
    this.flag = this.flags[0];    
  }
```

Comment: but showing error static injector error.(parent component .ts pages folder and child component .ts theme folder)two component different folder

Comment: folder not matter

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access property using component instance without doing **ViewChild**

here's is an example

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Data, AppService } from '../../app.service';
import { emailValidator, matchingPasswords } from '../../theme/utils/app-validators';
import { TopMenuComponent } from '../../theme/components/top-menu/top-menu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss'],
  providers: [TopMenuComponent]
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public router:Router, public snackBar: MatSnackBar,private appservie:AppService, private topMenu: TopMenuComponent)
   {
     localStorage.clear()
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])] 
    });

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirmPassword': ['', Validators.required]
    },{validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')});

  }

  public onLoginFormSubmit(values:Object):void {
    console.log(values)
    this.appservie.loginuser(JSON.stringify(values)).subscribe(response =>{
      var data = response
      console.log(data)
      console.log(data['user']['username'])
      localStorage.setItem('username',data['user']['username'])
      console.log(this.topMenu.Message);
    })
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);

    }
  }

  public onRegisterFormSubmit(values:Object):void {
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
      this.snackBar.open('You registered successfully!', '×', { panelClass: 'success', verticalPosition: 'top', duration: 3000 });
    }
  }

}
```

i have updated **constructor** and **onLoginFormSubmit()** method

Comment: but showing error static injector error.(parent component .ts pages folder and child component .ts theme folder)two component different folder .

Comment: add `TopMenuComponent` in provider... i will update my answer as well

Comment: checkout this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5igdd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: If this answer helpful to you then please vote up and accept.

Comment: I Have doubt parent html is not display .how to display the parent html once call parent method automatically html also working how to acheive it.any suggestion.

Comment: You can access methods, if you want display parent view then you have to navigate to that component.